# I couldn't import 'Existing Maven Projects' of i-jetty

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, ijetty

[They said](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/wiki/BuildingConsoleWebApplication),

cd $IJETTY_HOME/console

mvn clean install

This will produce a war file in $IJETTY_HOME/console/webapp/target, and also the apk in $IJETTY_HOME/console/apk/target (although as we mentioned, you're probably not interested in that).

but I got following error (...oh, my god. I can not upload image ;0 )

---

**

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (generate-dex) @ console ---
Unable to access jarfile ${env.ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] I-Jetty :: Console Parent ......................... SUCCESS [0.241s]
[INFO] I-Jetty :: Console Webapp ......................... FAILURE [2.431s]
[INFO] I-Jetty :: Console Android Installer .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.122s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 08 19:33:47 KST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (generate-dex) on project console: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :console**
```

---

and I tried 'Building with Eclipse'

finally, I got following error similar with the one.

on Import Maven Projects,

---

**exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (1 errors)

maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run(1 errors) 

maven-depoendency-plugin:2.3:unpack-dependencies(1 error)**

---

Help me, plz.

I installed maven plug-in 1.3 with eclipse on Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I solved it by myself.

I missed export android sdk path (export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android/android-sdk-linux_86)

and I edited pom.xml

from

```
<artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.0-beta-5</version>
```

to

```
<artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
```

thanks.